# multi-variable optimization in matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I need to minimize a function that involves two variables. The problem is that this function is not directly related to those two variables. Many other variables are to be calculated first, which are actually functions of the first two variables, and then they're used to calculate the function. And I can't put the function and the two variables in one equation. So, what options do I have in matlab to solve this optimization problem?

Thanks

Comment: Show a concrete code for optimization objective function and constraints

Comment: you will need to write some kind of wrapper that takes those two variable (and maybe some static inputs that you can shadow by an anonymous function handle -- google it) and calls all those sub-functions and eventually returns a single cost value. Than you can use plenty of algorithms, e.g. the most powerful in Matlab: `fmincon`